# issue in locating google map

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps, vue.js

I'm working with **Google Maps** with *vue.j* using **Laravel** and I'm facing a issue while locating any other place on *map* and it is not showing any error in  browser. Moreover, *google markers* are also not working. The code is given below.

```js
var app = new Vue({

 el: '#app',
  mounted(){
  var self = this;
   this.$on('google.maps:init', function(){
     self.createMap()
    });
  },
  data:{
   address : ''

  },
 methods: {
  createMap: function(){
   var map= new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('#map'),{

  center: {lat: 35, lng: -85},
  zoom:5
 });
  }
 },

 locateAddress: function (){
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var vm = this;
  geocoder.geocoder({ address: this.address}, function(results, status){

   if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
    vm.map.SetCenter(result[0].geometry.location);
   }
   
   new google.maps,Markers({
    map: vm.map,
    position: results[0].geometry.location
   });
  });
 }
});
```

```css
body, htl {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#map{
 width:100%;
   height:500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('main.css')}}">
 
</head>
<body>

 
 <div id="app">
 <form>
  <input type="text" id="address" v-model="address" name="">
  <button type="submit">Locate</button>
 </form>
   <div id="map"></div>
   <pre>@{{$data | json}}</pre>
 </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{asset('google.js')}}"></script>

 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAm7TbF3tnErWC0U-Kwdp_8FfdJIbgZBqU &callback=app.createMap" async defer></script>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this **fetchAddress** function instead of **locateAddress**. This functions works and searches required places.

```js
fetchAddress: function(address){
  new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({ address: this.address }, function(results, status) {
   if(status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                         center: results[0].geometry.location,
                            zoom: 5

                        }
                     )}
            });
        }
 }
});
```